# Export includes hidden items

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Report which includes an optional table. This has its visibility controlled by a user parameter.

When exporting to CSV file the hidden data gets included when it shouldn't.

How do I prevent it from being exported?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this was not the expected behavior, but it is by design. In terms of a workaround, one option would be to use subreports instead of just tables. For example, you could have a main report that lists the parameter values in a table. Each one would have an Action that takes you to the appropriate subreport when you click on it. The expression for the Action can be a conditional statement to accommodate future changes in the values. Then you could easily export without worrying about visibility.

Comment: What I did was to create a new, smaller report, which excludes the optional info. Seemed the easiest workaround...